# Solr: One word query does not match three word indexed value

Tags: search, solr, lucene

One of my documents has a `title` attribute with the value `Poésie pour pouvoir`. When I query `q=title:poesie`, no results are found. `q=title:poesie pour` finds the document, though.

`title` is of type `text`. Excerpt from my schema.xml:

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query isn't searching the title field only - it's also searching the default search field. The query is parsed as "title:poesie default_field:pour". The second part is what's generating the hit.

You can use the `debugQuery` parameter to see how your query is being parsed. Use the *analysis* page under the Solr admin page to see why the title value doesn't match (input "Poésie pour pouvoir" under "indexed" value and "poesie" under query value).

Comment: Thanks! Rookie mistake. That explains the match for `title:poesie pour`, but `title:poesie+pour` still doesn't return satisfactory results. Why doesn't that match?

Comment: As mentioned, use the analysis page under the Solr admin interface to see how the values are transformed any why the ending tokens doesn't match.